# Tapir Custom Codec

Tags: scala, codec, circe, tapir

I am stuck at a place, I am using scala, tapir and circe.

```
sealed abstract class S1Error extends Product with Serializable
object S1Error {
  final case class SError(error: SMError) extends S1Error
}
sealed abstract class SMError(message: String)
object SMError {
  final case class SVError(message: String) extends SMError(message)
}
```

For tapir errorOut I am using this

```
val schemaVersionError: EndpointOutput.StatusMapping[SError] = statusMappingValueMatcher(
      StatusCode.BadRequest,
      jsonBody[SError]
        .description("XXXX.")
    ) {
      case SMError(SVError(_)) => true
      case _                                  => false
    }
```

Now because of this structure, the API result I get is

```
{
    "error": {
        "SVError": {
            "message": "XXXXG"
        }
    }
}
```

where as ideally I would want a response as

```
"message": "XXXXG"
```

I can not change the error structure.
Is there a way to wrap this error using a custom codec to get the result as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tapir codec is derived from Circe's decoder and encoder.

What you see is the default way of encoding case classes by circe.

Circe provides the possibility to encode case classes the way you described with `deriveUnwrappedEncoder` from [circe-generic-extras](https://github.com/circe/circe-generic-extras). Unfortunately, it doesn't compile for `SMError` (probably derivation mechanism gets confused by your abstract class hierarchy).

What you can do is just creating encoder manually:

```scala
sealed abstract class S1Error extends Product with Serializable

object S1Error {
  final case class SError(error: SMError) extends S1Error

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SError] = Encoder[SMError].contramap(_.error)
  // or you can use deriveUnwrappedEncoder from circe-generic-extras:
  // implicit val encoder: Encoder[SError] = deriveUnwrappedEncoder
}

//I also needed to make message a field in SMError
sealed abstract class SMError(val message: String)
object SMError {
  final case class SVError(override val message: String) extends SMError(message)

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SMError] = Encoder.encodeJsonObject.contramap{s => JsonObject("message" -> s.message.asJson)}
}
```

Response now looks like:

```json
{
    "message": "XXXXG"
}
```

Comment: Krzysztof Atłasik can you explain me how does this encoding works.

Comment: Also, I have 
  `final case class Bulk(accepted: Seq[String], failed: Seq[FailedRecord])
  final case class FailedRecord(record: Option[String], error: S1Error)`

How can I make sure that when I print json for `Bulk`, I get proper encoded message for `S1Error`

Comment: Such that in this case I should get
`{
  "accepted": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ],
  "failed": [
    {
      "record": "jk",
      "error": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: I made it work by doing 
`implicit val signalErrorEncoder: Encoder[S1Error] = Encoder.instance {
    case foo@ S1Error. SError(_) => foo.asJson
  }`

But this work as long as 
`final case class Bulk(accepted: Seq[String], failed: Seq[FailedRecord])` 
`final case class FailedRecord(record: Option[String], error: S1Error)`
and 
`implicit val signalErrorEncoder: Encoder[S1Error] = Encoder.instance {
    case foo@ S1Error. SError(_) => foo.asJson
  }`

are inside S1Error object 

But in my case both `Bulk` and `Failed` are in different classes and the above solution does not work